# Cant Update State After navigator.pop()

Tags: android, flutter, native, mobile-development

I am still learning flutter and i encountered a problem. I have 2 screens one of them is ProductList and another one is ProductAdd. Problem is when user clicks on add button program navigates to ProductAdd. User enters some info and click OK. ProductAdd does some sqflite job and calls the navigate.pop() but the state doesnt change after user returns to homepage it changes when i reload the page.
Here is the productlist.(productCount is the one i want to update when navigate.pop get called)

```
 ListView buildProductList() {
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: productCount,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int position){
      return Card(
        color: Colors.cyan,
        elevation: 2.0,
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.black12,child: Text("p"),),
          title: Text(this.products[position].name),
          subtitle: Text(this.products[position].description),
          onTap: (){},
        ),
      );
    });
 }

void gotoProductAdd() async {
  var result = await Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ProductAdd()));
  getProducts();
}

void getProducts() async{
  var productsFuture =  dbHelper.getProducts();
  //data is the data coming from sqflite db
  productsFuture.then((data){
    this.products = data;
    productCount = data.length;
  });
}
```

}

Here is the ProductAdd(where navigator.pop() executed)

```
 void addProduct() async{
var result = await 
dbHelper.insert(Product(name:txtName.text,
description:txtDescription.text,
unitPrice:double.tryParse(txtUnitPrice.text)));
Navigator.pop(context,true);
```

}

Comment: I think you should use navigator.pushreplacement. Because navigator.pop will only pop current screen which will be on top of the previous screen. So, the screen below doesnot build and give you same screen

Comment: @JalakamKiran should i change anything else other than pushReplacement?

Comment: 1.Never see setState(). Read about it.
2. Remove async where you don't have await(suggestion)

Comment: On your products page, when are you calling `getProducts()`?